# Cut Trim url in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am receiving an URL from internet request in Java, but URL contains invalid parameters.

somehow if we manually remove the parameters, the URL works, how I can achieve this in java.

**"https://i1.wp.com/www.xxxxxxxxx.xx/xxxxxx/uxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx&ssl=1"**

The URL I am getting in a string

I only want this.

**www.xxxxxxxxx.xx/xxxxxx/uxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx&ssl=1**

Comment: search for `/www` and substring.

Comment: can u share any example ?

Comment: search for /www. and then substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the beginning of the URL is always the same (https://i1.wp.com/....) then you can just split the string and take the second part.

```
String s = "https://i1.wp.com/www.xxxxxxxxx.xx/xxxxxx/uxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx&ssl=1";
String[] parts = s.split("https://i1.wp.com/");
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

This produces an output of:

```
www.xxxxxxxxx.xx/xxxxxx/uxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx&ssl=1
```

Comment: can we search for '.com/  because in "https://i1.wp.com/" the parameter i1 is not the same each time

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the part that has to be cut away varies in length or not. You could use @Casey Williams' solution for fixed URLs, or just trim the first 17 chars. If the beginning URL varies in length, you could use regular expressions. So you should clarify your question.

Comment: actually length remains same . parameter i1 is shuffled between i1 to i9 randamly